# Histograms with Normalized Data?

Tags: normalization, histogram

I have two datasets I am looking to perform some simple visualization on. One dataset is approx. seven times larger than the other.

My first step was to compare the distribution of each, and I thought a histogram would be a good way to do this. The question is, because of the differences in size between the datasets, would normalizing them be a  logical step? The unaltered histogram looks like this:

[image: Histogram on my two unaltered datasets]

I guess at the simplest level, this tells me something; the distribution of the blue dataset sits within the distribution of red dataset, with the exception of a much longer tail - but it doesn't seem a fantastic way to approach the task.

Would min-max normalizing (or something similar) make sense in this case?

**Edit:** Following on from a comment regarding using density instead, this seems to improve visualization slightly (see below). Would this negate the need for any normalization?

[image: Histogram on my two unaltered datasets using density rather than counts]

Comment: Or your y-axis could be density rather than frequency.

Comment: @user2974951 thanks. that improves the output somewhat. Are there better ways to represent this that might make better use of the empty space?

Comment: I don't think so. The two distributions are clearly different, so any "correct" transformation should show a similar picture. You could try different bins (say wider bins) or truncating the axis, to get a more zoomed in picture, but otherwise... this is it. Or maybe a different plot, say a boxplot.

Comment: You might also be interested in [Q-Q plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) for comparing the quantiles of two distributions. This is a useful complement to plotting density estimates, as different types of information are more visually apparent in each type of plot.